# Constructing a temporary table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I am trying to make a sub-table that "stores" a decode between two values, because I need to use that decode multiple times. Let's say these are my tables:

```
Table Person
Name    Number_name
Jeremy  One
Thomas  Two
Stephen Three
```

my current SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    decode (number_name,
    'one',1,
    'two',2,
    'three',3,
    'four',4)
    num
    FROM person where name = 'Jeremy'
    and (some other condition)
UNION SELECT
    decode (number_name,
    'one',1,
    'two',2,
    'three',3,
    'four,4)
    num
    FROM Person
    where Name <> "Jeremy"
    and (some other condition)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT num from my_temp_table where name = "Jeremy" and (some other condition)
union select num from my_temp_table where name <> "Jeremy" and (some other condition)
...
```

where my_temp_table is constructed during that query (it ceases to exist when the query finishes running) and will look like

```
Table my_temp_table
Name  num
One   1
Two   2
Three 3
Four  4
```

And hopefully I can do this without the ol' "select one name,1 num from dual union all ..."

Is this doable?

Comment: How about a deterministic function? Alessandro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WITH` clause is sounds like the closest thing to what you're describing.  But that requires that you generate the data somehow.  Selecting from `DUAL` is likely the easiest option

```
WITH my_temp_table AS (
  SELECT 'One' name, 1 num from dual union all
  SELECT 'Two', 2 from dual union all
  SELECT 'Three', 3 from dual union all
  SELECT 'Four', 4 from dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM my_temp_table 
       JOIN person ON (<<some join condition>>)
 WHERE <<some predicate>>
```

Since you don't want to union a bunch of queries, you could do something like

```
WITH my_temp_table AS (
  select level num,
         initcap( to_char( to_date( level, 'J' ),
                           'JSP' )) name
    from dual
 connect by level <= 4
)
...
```